# Add icons to a TextField NativeScript

Tags: xhtml, uitextfield, textfield, nativescript

How to add icons to a TextField with NativeScript like you can see on the image: [here](http://sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg)

My xhtml code:

```
<StackLayout>
<Image src="res://logo_login" stretch="none" horizontalAlignment="center"></Image>

<TextField #username class="input" hint="GEBRUIKERSNAAM" [(ngModel)]="user.username" autocorrect="false" 
autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
<TextField #password class="input" hint="PASWOORD" secure="true" [(ngModel)]="user.password"></TextField>

<Button class="btn btn-primary btn-login icon" text="\e912 INLOGGEN" (tap)="login()"></Button>

<button  class="btn btn-forgot-pass" text="PASWOORD VERGETEN?" (tap)="forgotpass()"></button>
```

Comment: Are you sure that was the image? Also, your XHTML doesn't look like XHTML. It isn't even well-formed xml.

Comment: try using Icon Fonts as described here https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/icon-fonts.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out icon fonts for NativeScript:

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/icon-fonts

"...
Follow the instructions on the icon font webpage to determine the hex codes of each font glyph, i.e., icon. Add a Label component to your NativeScript app and bind the Label's text property to a one-letter string generated from the character code of the icon you want to show, i.e., String.fromCharCode(0xe903).

..."

I believe this is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your TextFields in a StackLayout with a horizontal orientation like

```
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
  <!--Your password TextField-->
  <TextField
    #password
    class="input"
    hint="PASWOORD"
    secure="true"
    [(ngModel)]="user.password"
  ></TextField>
  <!--You can then place the icon-->
  <Label class="fa" text="&#xf06e;" (tap)="toggleShow()"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```